# Can We use the VB6 PictureBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a Migrated Project which contains PictureBox Events.When it is migrated to VB.NET 2008 some events are converted which are not correct.Because the PictureBox in VB.NET is different to VB6 PictureBox.I want to know one thing that can we use the Same picture box in VB.NET also.I think which may help us to use the same events.Can we do like this ? It contains some events like Picture_paint,AutoRedraw,setPoint etc.It has some Twips and Pixel Calculation also.

Will this help ?Do we have any upgraded control in .NET equivalent to Picture box of VB6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way to accomplish your goal. Try to upgrade to the new PictureBox in VB.Net.
Yes, they are different, but, you can hardly say that the VB.Net version is less capable than the VB6 version.
If you upgrade, do it fully and you will not regret the decision in the future.

This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzt5x46b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) exposes the difference between the two controls

Comment: your correct........ need to update it other wise in later phase u will get more problems bcs Microsoft stopping the support for VB6

Comment: @Anandkumar It is a good idea to upgrade to the .Net version, but Microsoft are [continuing to support the VB6 runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx)

Comment: @MarkJ, and that's good luckily for me and for my VB6 programs, but the OP said that they have migrated to VB.NET 2008. Still he wants to use the old PictureBox inside a VB.NET environment. That's wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @Steve I agree. Which is why I originally said "it is a good idea to upgrade to the .Net version".

Answer (score 0):

Converting from VB6 to VB.Net is not easy process almost all your events will not work you need to find equivalent events in vb.Net

Go with this [link](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-dotnet-l/converting-vb6-picturebox-to-vbnet-2029031)

Comment: yes @anandkumar Its too tough to compare also.We dont know exactly how it looks in the runtime ? Another Solution like adding the same VB6 picture box control in VB.NET.Will this work?

Comment: you can use it but many functionality and events will not work

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the controls in VB6 and VB.NET work differently so upgrading line for line is not really possible.

As a hlaf way house you could create an ActiveX Control (OCX) in VB6 containing your picturebox which raised the events required to the application and then use this in VB.NET

[This tutorial](http://cuinl.tripod.com/tutorials/ocx-11.htm) may help you to get started